# Find an item in a List Using streams in java

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of persons. Each Person has a name and age.

I want to use a stream to find if the person is already in the list.

```
public void process (Person pItem) {
    Person curPerson = persons.stream().filter(x -> x.name.equals(pItem.name)).collect(.. ???)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Person curPerson= persons.stream().filter(x -> x.name.equals(pItem.name)).findFirst().orElse(null);
```

Comment: I think that's what i need , but what if i want to check on name and age ?

Comment: You can add age: 

Person curPerson= persons.stream().filter(x -> x.name.equals(pItem.name) && x.age.equals(pitem.age)).findFirst().get();

Comment: Don't use `.get()` here unless you are certain that the person is already in the list. Otherwise it will throw a `NoSuchElementException`

Comment: Ik have indeed this Exception...how to i solve this ?

Comment: replace `get()` with `orElse("not found")`.

Comment: @Pavlo Plynko: `orElse("not found")` does not work, unless you proceed with the common base type of `Person` and `String`. If you want to assign the result to a variable of type `Person`, you can only use `orElse(null)` or use a dummy person instance representing the unknown or absent person.

Comment: Sure, sorry for this. And thanks for your comment. On my IDE I've tested it with String instead Person, so it's from my inattention.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Stream.anyMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-)

```
public boolean process (Person pItem) {
    return persons.stream().anyMatch(x -> x.name.equals(pItem.name));
}
```

Comment: and if you want to check also if the age is the same ?

Comment: if person contains only name and age, and you have equals defined, you could do `persons.stream().anyMatch(Person::equals)`
Otherwise, you could do `persons.stream().anyMatch(x -> x.name.equals(pItem.name) && x.age.equals(pItem.age))`

Comment: if youcan't find a match using this how can you check ....like in .net if result is Nothing